# why does my program take in the values the first time and skip my first cin.getline() on the next run?

Tags: pointers, function-pointers

Hi guys im new to pointers and just doing this from an online question. my code runs and complies fine.
im curious what am i doing wrong that makes my program run fine on the first time then not run properly on the second... third and so on. please advice!! thanks in advance!
here are the codes:

```
void continueProg(char& cont)
{
    cout << "Continue (Y/N)?: ";
    cin >> cont;
    if(cont=='y'||cont=='Y')
    {
        cont = 'Y';
    }
    else if((cont=='n')||(cont=='N'))
    {
        cont = 'n';
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter valid alaphelbet!\n";
        continueProg(cont);
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin.ignore` 15 chars

Comment: cin.clear();cin.ignore(100,'\n');

Comment: sorry but may i ask like if i dont include it why does it screw up?

Comment: If you dont include it, then when a person types ahead/improper data, that data is left in the buffer which will then be read by the next cin.getline function. If you worked in C, you would know what I mean when it came to C's scanf

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
UserEWord.W1=new char;
...
cin.getline(UserEWord.W1,'\n');
```

`cin` is of type `std::istream`, so the method you're actually calling is [`std::istream::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

As you can see from the documentation, the first argument must be a pointer to (what should be) an *array* of chars, and the second argument `n` must be the size of the array that you permit the method to write to (including the terminating NUL). The optional third argument is the char delimiter, which, incidentally, defaults to a line feed (`'\n'`) if you omit it.

You allocated `W1` (and `W2`) with just a single char, meaning there's only room for one char in the buffer. You passed `'\n'` as `n` in the call to `getline()`, which you obviously intended to be the delimiter. But the end result is the char value (10) will be taken as the size of the buffer, which is too large. Any non-empty input will overflow the buffer, leading to undefined behavior.

There's a second problem here, which is the answer to your exact question:

```
void continueProg(char& cont)
{
    cout << "Continue (Y/N)?: ";
    cin >> cont;
    if(cont=='y'||cont=='Y')
```

Here you're streaming in a single char of input to `cont`, because `cont` is just a single char. But the user will almost certainly type more than just a single char, at least due to the terminating line feed sent when he/she presses enter. That additional unread input will be left in the system's input buffer until such time as your program again attempts to read input from `cin`, which occurs back at the `getline()` call I quoted above. So the unread input will end up being read at that time, up to the unread line feed, which is why all iterations of your program after the first will appear to skip reading word 1.

To solve both of the above problems, I recommend using the global [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function that allows you to read directly into a `std::string`, guaranteeing you get a complete line, with no size limit. For example:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input );
```

**Edit:** In response to your comment, no, you cannot do that. The `std::string` type is a container class provided by the C++ standard library, and is a completely different animal from the language's native `char`/`char*` types. You usually cannot use one directly where the other is required (although it should be mentioned that you can always pass a `const char*` or `char*` where a `std::string` or `const std::string&` IN argument is expected, and the implicit [conversion constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) will be called to convert the `const char*` or `char*` to a `const std::string&`, but that only applies to IN arguments, not OUT arguments, as we have here with `std::getline()`, which takes a non-const `std::string&`) (and it should also be mentioned that if you have a `std::string`, const or not, you can call the [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method on it to get a `const char*` pointing to the contents).

If you really want to stick with an array of `char`s, then to solve the first problem you have to do something like this:

```
#define MAX 100
...
UserEWord.W1=new char [MAX]; // allocate an array of MAX chars
...
cin.getline(UserEWord.W1,MAX);
```

And to solve the second problem you can use `cin.ignore();` as Isaiah suggested:

```
void continueProg(char& cont)
{
    cout << "Continue (Y/N)?: ";
    cin >> cont;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n'); // requires #include <limits>
    if(cont=='y'||cont=='Y')
```